# Can tidal turbines be used as run of the river generators

Tags: renewable-energy

I see that the British government is supporting a project to generate energy using [tidal turbines](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-north-east-orkney-shetland-57991351).

I am wondering if the same design would be effective and economic also for run of the river power generation. By combining the two production cost might be reduced, even though there would be a limit because I suspect that such turbines could be placed mainly on navigable rivers and places where they would not interfere with river navigation would not be so many.

Comment: There was one planned of the edge of Southern Ireland - you could do some research...

Comment: Have a look at https://waterotor.com/.

Answer (score 0):

The project you are referencing is probably one of the first commercial, so I would be very surprised if it were immediately competitive to other technologies.

So, IMHO its too early to judge effectiveness and economic viability,  I will offer a comparison for wind energy. The  reason is that both have moving parts, and convert a fluid energy. (Comparing it with solar would introduce other issues like power availability etc).

|  | Tidal generator | Wind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Designation | ORbital O2 | Vestas V90-3.0 |
| Power output | 2MW | 3 MW |
| Weight | 680 ton | 111 ton rotor and nacelle (285 ton the tower) |
| Structure | 74m long tube | 110m tall tube |
| Rotor diameter | two 20m rotors | one 90m rotors |
| Working environment | submerged in water | above the water |

From this small table, it is obvious that for delivering less power output the size of the tidal turbine is significantly smaller (even if you include the tower).

Additionally, the tidal turbine is expected to work underwater and produce electricity, so it has added requirements for water tight requirements, which are simply not there in the wind turbines.

Finally, if you check the article, the company received a subsidy of £3.4m from the Scottish government's Saltire Tidal Energy Challenge Fund (also there were public lenders but the cost is undisclosed but I expect to match that). In comparison, the installation cost in 2021 for a wind turbine per MW is in the order of $1,300,000 USD per megawatt ([source](https://weatherguardwind.com/how-much-does-wind-turbine-cost-worth-it/#:%7E:text=%241%2C300%2C000%20USD%20per%20megawatt.,on%20wind%20turbine%20operational%20cost.)). I.e. less than £1m per MW. So you can understand that any comparison -at least at the moment - is simply not fair.

Answer (score 0):

In any place that water moves one could extract energy from it.  The problem with doing it in a river is that it's hard to capture the energy, and it also places a generator in the middle of a river.  Putting a generator out in the ocean is no big deal, tho my guess is that the location of your example has islands creating larger than normal tidal flows.  The typical way to capture river energy is using a dam.

Comment: I am not a mechanical guy but did design the "run-the-river" power generating facility by a riverbank. The concept was similar to the dam in utilizing the thrust from the water flow but does not block the entire navigation channel. It is rare though because of the unfavorable economic scale. Also, it kills living things in the review :)